# .NET Core 1.1 MVC not rendering correctly via VS2017 IDE

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core, visual-studio-2017

I have a simple .NET Core MVC solution based on a standard template which when started via the VS 2017 IDE does not seem to be rendering Bootstrap elements correctly. This happens whether I use IIS Express or Kestrel, and is browser-independent. But when I start it up from the prompt using **dotnet run** and browse to it manually it's fine. When I view the page source the correctly rendering version is (as per the environments defined in _Layout.cshtml) taking Bootstrap, JQuery et al from a CDN, whereas when run through the IDE it's using Bower\NPM packages under the web root.

I've tried rebuilding the dependencies to no avail. Static files are set. Any pointers as to what else to look at ?

[image: Wrong.]

[image: Right.]

Comment: could you check that your stylesheet is loading correctly?

Comment: Upon investigation, after clearing the cache, it doesn't seem like *anything* from wwwroot\lib can be found, it's all coming back 404.

Comment: did you enable static files middleware in your startup? `app.UseStaticFiles();`

Comment: also could you ensure that you have all static on the disk within wwwroot directory?

Comment: I *thought* I had UseStaticFiles() but I had removed it to test. It's back now. Duh. Now it's resolving all the sources correctly.

Comment: great, then I can post answer for your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add `app.UseStaticFiles();` line to your `Startup` class so your statics can be served by static files middleware

Comment: That's essentially it although there were issues with Bootstrap and JQuery versions too.